# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.15.8 Laravel Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-valet

Two days now I try to spot an issue with this provider.

**MY SETUP**
PHP VERSION: PHP 7.2.14
Zend Engine v3.2.0
Laravel Valet

**Clearing cache**
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload

**FILE : .env**

```
APP_URL=https://mywebsite.test/
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

FACEBOOK_KEY=19242542********
FACEBOOK_SECRET=60c3c0a346******
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URI=ht
```

tps://mywebsite.test/login/facebook/callback/

**CONFIGURING FACEBOOK CORECTLY**

**ROUTES**

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 
'SocialLoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 
'SocialLoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SocialLoginController extends Controller
{

public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

/**
 * Obtain the user information from GitHub.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $socialite = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();
    dd($socialite);
}
}
```

**ISSUE**
When I login my account prompts me to continue as the user I am and that works.
In the database a I see a record in session when I login.
And I wait for 30"-60" and i get

**504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.15.8**

Answer (score 3):

Solving this issue is easy: just open the file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/valet/valet.conf` and add the following lines to the block

```
location ~ .php$ { } :
proxy_connect_timeout 600;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
```

Now all you have to do is to run on your valet restart terminal and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

504 Gateway issues mean that the server timed out attempting to reach a remote server in that case probably facebook with socialite you will need to provide the redirect link that you use exactly as the one in your facebook app settings.